# How to print lines of file that start with d and end with number

Tags: linux

I have this file named `korad` and I need to print all lines of this file that start with "d" and end with number, This is what I tried:

```
grep "^d*[0-9]$" korad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
grep "^d" korad | grep "[0-9]$"
```

This first filters the lines, starting with letter "d" and afterwards filters those results with the lines, ending with a number. Like that, you don't need to worry about anything being present between the first and the last character.

In case you don't understand the vertical bar, it's called a pipe, which is (amongst others) explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^d(?:.*)\d$' korad
```

To get all lines starting with `d` and ending with a digit

---

###### [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G7Qog5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting:

```
 grep "^d.*[[:digit:]]$" korad
```